# CountDownTimer in surfaceview

Tags: android, timer

I'm trying to create a countdowntimer and display it on the canvas. Here's how I display it.

```
public class DrawView extends SurfaceView {
private Paint textPaint = new Paint();
Bitmap GameBg;
DisplayMetrics metrics;
int screenWidth = 0;
int screenHeight = 0;
Rect dest;
Paint paint;
String timer;
public DrawView(Context context) {
     super(context);
     // Create out paint to use for drawing
     textPaint.setARGB(255, 200, 0, 0);
     textPaint.setTextSize(60);
     // This call is necessary, or else the 
     // draw method will not be called. 
     setWillNotDraw(false);

     GameBg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.gembackground);
     metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
     screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
     screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
     dest = new Rect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
     paint = new Paint();
     paint.setFilterBitmap(true);

     new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             timer = String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000);
         }

         public void onFinish() {
         }
         }.start();

     }

     @Override
     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
     // A Simple Text Render to test the display
     canvas.drawBitmap(GameBg, null, dest, paint);
     canvas.drawText(timer, screenWidth - 50, screenHeight - 50, paint);

     }
```

}

I can display the timer but it doesn't countdown. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never do anything with the new value in `timer`. Try something like this:

```
 new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         timer = String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000);
         invalidate(); // Force the View to redraw
     }

     public void onFinish() {}
 }.start();
```

Comment: Well that did it. So I should always put and invalidate to make the view to redraw again?

Comment: You should try to invalidate the smallest region possible. Consider using this [`invalidate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) with the appropriate coordinates.